# Travis CI can't find header files in R package subdirectory

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I am trying to set up Travis-CI to build [this](https://github.com/weinstockj/htslibr) R package. The package builds locally with the following steps that closely mirror the build process on Travis (failed build [here](https://travis-ci.com/weinstockj/htslibr/jobs/193748107)):

```
git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/weinstockj/htslibr.git weinstockj/htslibr
cd weinstockj/htslibr/
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd htslibr/
R -e 'install.packages("Rcpp")'
R CMD build .
```

Travis fails with an error that suggests it cannot find a header file that is in a sub-directory of `htslibr/src`. Why does R CMD build fail to find the header on Travis (again, no issue locally)?

Travis set up is [here](https://github.com/weinstockj/htslibr/blob/master/.travis.yml) , and locally I am also using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here an extract from the failed build log:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/Rtmpy1bhv4/Rinst23036acf1e4/htslibr/inst/include
cp htslib/htslib/*.h /tmp/Rtmpy1bhv4/Rinst23036acf1e4/htslibr/inst/include
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/home/travis/R-bin/include   -fpic  -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/home/travis/R-bin/include   -fpic  -g -O2 -c util.cpp -o util.o
util.cpp:2:24: fatal error: htslib/hts.h: No such file or directory
```

We see that while the headers are copied to `/tmp/Rtmpy1bhv4/Rinst23036acf1e4/htslibr/inst/include`, this directory is not on the include path. You can fix this by adding

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS
```

to `Makevars` (`STRICT_R_HEADERS` is not needed but ["best practice"](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/898)) and using `#include <hts.h>` in `util.cpp`. However, I am not convinced that it is correct to copy the  header files to `inst/include` in the first place. After all, these header files do not represent an API that your packge is providing to other packages. Instead, it is the API of a library that you package uses *internally*. I would therefore suggest to not copy the header files and use

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -Ihtslib -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS
```

in `Makevars`.

BTW, [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) advocates a different usage pattern for the targets:

```
all: $(SHLIB)
$(SHLIB): <any other needed targets>
```

Though this point is irrelevant if you follow my suggestion to not copy the headers.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I tried your suggestion - unfortunately same error: https://travis-ci.com/weinstockj/htslibr/jobs/194016747

Comment: @JoshW. Right, I overlooked the relative path used for the `include`. I have corrected the answer and added another possibility.

Comment: I added that, as well as "-Lhtslib" to PKG_LIBS, and now it finds the header files. Thanks for your answer. Now it is unable to find the .so file after created the shared library : https://travis-ci.com/weinstockj/htslibr/jobs/194034525 . Think this can be solved by adding rpath to PKG_LIBS ?

Comment: @JoshW. Typically one builds a static library (`.a`), c.f. https://github.com/rstub/swephR/blob/master/src/Makevars.in. Using `rpath` might work, but I am not sure how portable that is. Also, you would have to install `libhts.so` along with the package, which is not done by default. That it works locally probably means that you have `htslib` installed in a standard location, right?

Comment: Idea to use rpath comes from here - https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Unix_002dalikes . I think it is OK for now if it is not completely portable. htslib is not installed in a standard location locally.